# Error : Cannot create a data reader for dataset using reportviewer (.rdlc report)

Tags: c#, rdlc, ssrs-2012

I have read all the potential solutions to the error (Cannot create a data reader for dataset ) and none have worked so far here is my code snippet (the correct parameters are being passed in with data ) :

```
public void GenerateRDLC(Finteq.Types.ReportingServices.ReportParameters     p_ReportParameters, Stream p_ReportDefinition, ref string p_ReportOutput)
    {
      try
      {
        ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
        DataTable customDataTable = new DataTable();
        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string fileExtension = string.Empty;
        string filetype = string.Empty;
        string[] streamIDs;
        Warning[] warnings = null;

        //reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(p_ReportDefinition);
        reportViewer.localReport.DataSources.Clear();//added
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(p_ReportParameters.ReportName, p_ReportParameters.ReportDataSource));
        reportViewer.localReport.DataSources.Refresh; // added



        string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>";
        byte[] reportFile;
        try
        {
          reportFile = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render(p_ReportParameters.ReportFormat.ToString(), deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileExtension, out streamIDs, out warnings);

          using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(p_ReportParameters.ReportTemplateFullPath, FileMode.Create))
          {
            fileStream.Write(reportFile, 0, reportFile.Length);
            p_ReportOutput = p_ReportParameters.ReportTemplateFullPath;
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          throw new Exception("Failed to render local report, details: " + ex.Message + "Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
        throw new Exception("Generate_RDLC_Report::GenerateRDLC - " + exception.Message);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: looks, like p_ReportParameters.ReportDataSource is DataSet, should be DataTable or see other overloads https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportdatasource.aspx